# Any Facebook PHP SDK v4.06 working Canvas App Example? Cant Get a valid session

Tags: php, facebook, canvas

```
<?php
// include required files form Facebook SDK
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookCanvasLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookPermissionException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphUser.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphLocation.php' );
include ("fns.php");

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookCanvasLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\GraphLocation;
// start session
session_start();

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'XXXXXXXXXXx','yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy' );

$helper = new FacebookCanvasLoginHelper();

try {

          $session = $helper->getSession();



} catch (Exception $ex) {
 // echo $ex->getMessage();

}

if($session)
{
    $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
    try{

         $response = $request->execute();
         $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
         //echo  print_r( $graphObject, 1 );
         $fid = $graphObject->getProperty('id'); echo $fid;
         $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email'); echo $femail;
         $ffirst_name = $graphObject->getProperty('first_name'); echo $ffirst_name;
       } catch (Exception $ex) {
       // echo $ex->getMessage();

       }
}
```

?>

First off, I am not an expert PHP coder, so I do not understand a lot of things, but I do know how to use a working example. I made a Canvas App that was working fine. Then I installed ssl and it no longer works. The code itself is a mess from my efforts to fix the problem.

Can I just get a working example that echos user public data using FacebookCanvasLoginHelper with the latest 4.06 PHP SDK? I can take it up from there if I can see that.

Since V4.0,  getsession() no longer seems to work. In V4.06 its supposed to have been fixed, but I still cant get it to work.

Thanks in advance

### **Edit**

I have added the relevant code. After debugging, i find that it appears $session is not valid or something because code execution never gets past "$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );". I cant seem to get anything echoed out after that. please any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What does your code look like and what does not work?

Comment: I have added the code. please take a look and see what needs to be done to echo out user details. I added a little Edit note to explain. Thanks.

Comment: When you try to get the session from the helper, maybe you can add a catch statement for the Facebook request exception, like documented in the sdk documentation  
    catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {  
        // When Facebook returns an error  
        echo $ex->getMessage();  
    }

Answer (score 0):

**If** it worked previously and you **ONLY** changed to SSL then the only thing that would cause the error and lack of session is a redirect mismatch.

Your old app redirect would be **http** and the new app redirect will be **https**

Change the Facebook app to reflect this change in the app redirect set up.

Answer (score 0):

php 5.4 is required.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in /var/www/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php on line 137

Comment: hmm .. doesn't look like an answer to me, is it?